# OkHttp reply me not in UTF8 but in Percent Encoding

Tags: java, rest, api, okhttp, machine-translation

im calling a GET Api (API of ModernMTT) with OkHttp (Last version), my problem is that the reply from the server is not in UTF-8 but in Percent Encoding, and i dont understand why, i try to set MINE in UTF-8 without result.
From CURL and Postman the server reply good.
So the problem is on OkHttp.
My code

```
public static String translate(String string) throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new FixEncodingInterceptor()).build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.modernmt.eu/translate?source=" + sourceLanguage + "&target=" + targetLanguage + "&q=" + string)
                .method("GET", null)
                .addHeader("MMT-ApiKey", apiKey)
                .build();
        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            String stringTranslated= Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
            ResponseMTT responseMTT = new Gson().fromJson(stringTranslated, ResponseMTT.class);
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return responseMTT.getData().getTranslation();
        }
    }
```

The response.body.string() return this format:

```
%22Sconto%20del%2020%:%20%3CPAColor0xFF66CC33%3EUtilities%20%E2%86%92%20Capacity%20of%20load%3CPAOldColor%3E.
```

Comment: What does the Content-Type header line contain?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set "Accept-Charset" header to UTF-8 and test your code?  I am assuming Postman is defaulting the accept charset header to utf-8.